# Excel COM interop - why are return types often dynamic?

Tags: c#, excel, com

stupid question possibly, but I'm working with Microsoft's Office/Excel Interop type library.

I've noticed that many return types are of "dynamic" type; for example,

```
Excel.Workbook wb = ...;
var ws = wb.ActiveSheet;
```

ws would be "dynamic" instead of returned as an "Excel.Worksheet" - but why is that?

I see the benefits of dynamic typed COM objects in case the type library isn't available, but in this case, it is.

So why the dynamic typing here?

The only potential thing I could think of right now is what when interop types are embedded, and then e.g. the .Worksheet property is accessed by reflection, so its type is not embedded but needs to be accessed. But that's a wild guess. The invonenience to effectively having to manually cast so many types seems quite big, so I assume there must be some fairly important design decision behind this

Comment: The Office interop object model was designed in its current form about 20 years ago.  That it lasted so long is quite a stunning feat of engineering.  One of the tricks they used is to not nail down types, giving them leeway to, in this case, return something else.  Not much a problem 20 years ago, client languages had little problem with late binding.  And not much of problem in C# anymore either, the addition of `dynamic` at version 4 was inspired in no small part by wanting to support Office programming better.  It was rather awful before.

Comment: I see, thanks Hans. So more of a legacy reason rather than anything based on current design requirements. Might think of wrapping this somehow into a custom type class that does the casting directly then

Comment: Do favor KISS.  All it takes is var ws = (Excel.WorkBook)wb.ActiveSheet;

Comment: Thanks for your input! That'd be my main motivation indeed, though in a different way - developing something like Excel's VBA editor, just in C#. Would ideally like users to script away easily - if they need to cast everything themselves, might be confusing .. so maybe i'll create a simple wrapper type.

Comment: I recommend you wrap the Interop Model through a custom set of interfaces of your own. This way, as well as being able to Unit Test your project, you can (if desired) strongly type the COM object members.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic)

> At compile time, an element that is typed as dynamic is assumed to
>   support any operation. Therefore, you do not have to be concerned
>   about whether the object gets its value from a COM API, from a dynamic
>   language such as IronPython, from the HTML Document Object Model
>   (DOM), from reflection, or from somewhere else in the program.
>   However, if the code is not valid, errors are caught at run time.
>
> .....
>
> Conversions between dynamic objects and other types are easy. This
>   enables the developer to switch between dynamic and non-dynamic
>   behavior.
>
> .....
>
> Many COM methods allow for variation in argument types and return type
>   by designating the types as object. This has necessitated explicit
>   casting of the values to coordinate with strongly typed variables in
>   C#. If you compile by using the /link (C# Compiler Options) option,
>   the introduction of the dynamic type enables you to treat the
>   occurrences of object in COM signatures as if they were of type
>   dynamic, and thereby to avoid much of the casting.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not quite sure I understand though. The first paragraph seems to be more like a general description of dynamic types - if I have a reference to an Excel COM object, could any of its return types (such as the workbooks in a worksheet or similar) really be non-COM objects?